# What is the optimal way to make external network requests using Axum, Tokio, and Hyper in Rust?

Tags: rust, reverse-proxy, rust-tokio, hyper, rust-axum

I have written pretty basic rust server which makes http call to defined url in environment variable, parse json response and return.

[Source Code](https://github.com/pratikgajjar/rustio)
| [Flamegraph - IO Call](https://github.com/pratikgajjar/rustio/blob/main/flamegraph.svg)
| [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pratikgajjar/rustio/blob/main/Dockerfile)
| [Flamegraph - Static Json](https://github.com/pratikgajjar/rustio/blob/main/flame-cpu-short.svg)

Nginx request -  throughput ~**30000** requests/second.

```
curl -v 172.31.50.91/
*   Trying 172.31.50.91...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 172.31.50.91 (172.31.50.91) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 172.31.50.91
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.20.0
< Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2023 07:58:39 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 36
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json
<
* Connection #0 to host 172.31.50.91 left intact
{"status": 200, "msg": "Good Luck!"}
```

Nginx and Rust server are running on separate ec2 instance c6a.large in same network.

In rust server I have 2 APIs

1. Returns static response => Throughput **47000** requests/second
2. Make HTTP request to Nginx server -> Parse Json -> Return parsed data. => Throughput **2462** requests/second. [Issue]

Similar benchmark done in GoLang which uses [Fiber](https://github.com/gofiber/fiber) as http server in prefork model, [json-iterator](https://github.com/json-iterator/go). It's able to make call to nginx and return response at rate ~**20000** requests/second. Which means there are no issues with infra/docker/client used to test rust server.

There must be something missing in my rust code which causes such regression when http call introduced.

Need help with understanding why this would happen and how to improve rust code.

Benchmark result

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-50-91 ~]$ hey -z 10s  http://172.31.50.22:80/io

Summary:
  Total:        10.0168 secs
  Slowest:      0.0692 secs
  Fastest:      0.0006 secs
  Average:      0.0203 secs
  Requests/sec: 2462.4534

  Total data:   813978 bytes
  Size/request: 33 bytes

Response time histogram:
  0.001 [1]     |
  0.007 [12766] |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  0.014 [1185]  |■■■■
  0.021 [227]   |■
  0.028 [494]   |■■
  0.035 [1849]  |■■■■■■
  0.042 [3840]  |■■■■■■■■■■■■
  0.049 [3127]  |■■■■■■■■■■
  0.055 [992]   |■■■
  0.062 [174]   |■
  0.069 [11]    |
```

My attempts to improve perf.

- Both golang and rust are running on docker container on same instance one at a time.
- System ulimit / somaxcon has been updated to not cause any bottleneck, since static response able to perform 47K rps, it shouldn't cause limitation
- Moved external url to lazy_static but it didn't improve performance

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref EXTERNAL_URL: String = env::var("EXTERNAL_URL").unwrap();
}
```

- Tried changing tokio flavour config, workerthreads = 2, 10, 16 - it didn't improve perf.

```rust
#[tokio::main(flavor = "multi_thread", worker_threads = 10)]
```

- Looked into how to make sure hyper network call is being done in tokio async compatible way -> Earlier It had **247** requests/second. Was able to improve IO call by 10x via moving to stream based response processing. Reaching 2400 but still there is scope to improve.

IO Call API - [GitHub Link](https://github.com/pratikgajjar/rustio/blob/bb893a864e3225f9448c76fa0ccaab23f9ec930c/src/main.rs#L35)

```rust
pub async fn io_call( State(state): State<AppState>) -> Json<IOCall> {
    let external_url = state.external_url.parse().unwrap();
    let client = Client::new();
    let resp = client.get(external_url).await.unwrap();
    let body = hyper::body::aggregate(resp).await.unwrap();

    Json(serde_json::from_reader(body.reader()).unwrap())
}
```

This usecase is very similar to reverse proxy server.

Comment: Can we get the source code for the Go server?

Comment: Not that this is the bottleneck, but consider parsing `external_url` ahead of time and storing `Uri` in `State`.

Comment: Check where is the bottleneck, the request or JSON handling (likely the request) by returning the text response from the request, and parsing constant json.

Comment: @chayim - 
> The request or JSON handling (likely the request) by returning the text response from the request, and parsing constant json.
^ Tried this earlier, json isn't a bottleneck - got 48139 rps with - x = "json string" then parse and return hardcoded value. 

> consider parsing external_url 
^ I think issue is with how tokio and hyper interact when it comes to making external call. 

I have included only io related code but have another api which makes postgres db call to select 1 row and I am getting 9000 RPS there,

Comment: Added flamegraph, can you take a look ?

Comment: Can you try storing the `Client` in your `AppState` and using it for your endpoints instead of recreating it each time?

Comment: @kmdreko you are hero , moving hyper client initialization fixed it, now getting 26876 requests / second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko)

Moving hyper client initialization to AppState resolved the problem.

[Git diff](https://github.com/pratikgajjar/rustio/commit/1885fd1e56e3eae156433a8e589e61422757f4fe)

```rust
 pub async fn io_call(State(state): State<AppState>) -> Json<IOCall> {
    let external_url = state.external_url.parse().unwrap();
    let resp = state.client.get(external_url).await.unwrap();
    let body = hyper::body::aggregate(resp).await.unwrap();

    Json(serde_json::from_reader(body.reader()).unwrap())
}
```

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-50-91 ~]$ hey -z 10s http://172.31.50.22:80/io


Summary:
  Total:        10.0026 secs
  Slowest:      0.0235 secs
  Fastest:      0.0002 secs
  Average:      0.0019 secs
  Requests/sec: 26876.1036

  Total data:   8871456 bytes
  Size/request: 33 bytes

Response time histogram:
  0.000 [1]     |
  0.003 [212705]        |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  0.005 [39980] |■■■■■■■■
  0.007 [10976] |■■
  0.010 [4259]  |■
  0.012 [794]   |
  0.014 [94]    |
  0.016 [17]    |
  0.019 [0]     |
  0.021 [4]     |
  0.023 [2]     |


Latency distribution:
  10% in 0.0006 secs
  25% in 0.0009 secs
  50% in 0.0013 secs
  75% in 0.0022 secs
  90% in 0.0038 secs
  95% in 0.0052 secs
  99% in 0.0083 secs

Details (average, fastest, slowest):
  DNS+dialup:   0.0000 secs, 0.0002 secs, 0.0235 secs
  DNS-lookup:   0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs
  req write:    0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0086 secs
  resp wait:    0.0018 secs, 0.0002 secs, 0.0234 secs
  resp read:    0.0001 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0109 secs

Status code distribution:
  [200] 268832 responses
```

Comment: Glad I could help :) It was only a guess, but by reusing the `Client`, it can reuse the underlying connection (a http/1.1 feature) so it doesn't have to redo the TCP handshake each request. Your Go code was probably doing this behind the scenes.

Comment: Here can we use same client to make network call to different api / host ? Is it possible that response gets mixed up due to use of same client ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same client for APIs without issue, it uses a pool of connections internally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to narrow down the possible cause... Here are a few pointers that should lead you in the right direction...

#### Server

- Did you check the CPU load on the server? That's probably the first thing you should take a look at.
- Did you make sure you've compiled in *release* mode?
- Are those JSONs small (if they are large, they might increase the CPU and network cost).

#### Test client

Is it possible that your test client is the bottleneck?

- Does it manage to send enough requests in parallel?
- You might want to check its CPU, RAM, etc. if there are signs the client can't send enough requests.
- If it is too far away, that would increase the latency. (But if you managed to achieve a lot more static requests from the *same* client/server machines, that shouldn't be the problem.)

#### Network

*The following shouldn't be the case if you've run the static/Go tests with the same setup, but just in case:*

- As previously mentioned, make sure you're not testing with too large JSONs.
- Make sure you are not hitting some limit in the number of concurrent requests. Sometimes AWS can limit/throttle your requests.

If the above doesn't help, try testing the same setup locally and see what you can achieve. If no difference, try with smaller JSONs and see if that helps.

Comment: > Did you check the CPU load on the server? That's probably the first thing you should take a look at.

It reaches 100% on both core, but that's expected as server would try to make full use of available resources. 

> Did you make sure you've compiled in release mode?
Yes, Check this dockerfile https://github.com/pratikgajjar/rustio/blob/main/Dockerfile 

> Are those JSONs small (if they are large, they might increase the CPU and network cost). 

It's small payload, as mentioned in question
`{"status": 200, "msg": "Good Luck!"}` ; GoLang server is making request to same nginx server

Comment: > Does it manage to send enough requests in parallel?
Yes I am using same hey utility with same params 
> You might want to check its CPU, RAM, etc. if there are signs the client can't send enough requests.
Client is in different ec2, and this isn't problems since it's able to send 47K requests per second
> If it is too far away, that would increase the latency.
Both in same vpc connected via private ip 

>Make sure you are not hitting some limit in the number of concurrent requests. Sometimes AWS can limit/throttle your requests. 

wouldn't it throttle static benchmark too?